# How can I use estimated parameters to calculate probabilities using a density function?

Tags: r

I used `qqplot` to find that my data is from the t distribution.  Then I used the `fitdistr` function to estimate the parameters of the model for the t distribution and I got a `df = 4`, `scale = 181.28`, and `location = 10.68`.  I then want to calculate the probability that `X <= -1` using the parameters of the model and my data.  How should I approach this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like

```
pt((-1 -10.68) / 181.28, df=4)
```

If in doubt, consult `help("pt")`